# jQuery .load is not loading a local html file inside a Cocoa WebView

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, macos, cocoa

I have a Cocoa WebView that displays a local HTML file. I'm trying use jQuery.load() to load another local HTML file into a div. My JavaScript code goes something like this:

```
$("#mydiv").load("test.html");  // test.html is a local file inside the app's bundle
```

I don't see any exceptions but it will not load the html inside the div. I'm using exactly the same code for an iOS app, and it works fine. I've also tried using XMLHttpRequest() and I can see the responseText fine.

Any advice? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could try putting a `$(document).ready` before the `.load()` to ensure the page is fully there before trying to load something new into it. Depending on load time I've had JS fail due to the targetted div not being there when it's trying to execute.

Comment: Actually the code is being executed after the DOM has loaded. I'm thinking is something related to Cocoa's WebView as the same code runs without issues under iOS, Android and Windows. Thanks for the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get around the problem by using jQuery.ajax instead. Here's how I did it:

```
jQuery.ajax({ 
     url: "test.html", dataType: "html" 
}).done(function( responseHtml ) {
     $("#mydiv").html(responseHtml);
});
```

Hope it helps someone!

Comment: Doesn't work to me, same as doing `.load` on the jQuery object.

Answer (score 3):

A nice little work around just replace home.html with your local html file and content with your div id

```
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="home.html" ></object>';
```

*works in Chrome, Firefox, and IE enjoy!*

Answer (score 0):

```
var $div = $('div#something');
$div.load("test.html");
```

Comment: I know it sounds like a simple answer, but it seems to me like my issue is related to Cocoa's WebViews and not jQuery. Your code is equivalent. Thanks anyways.